# localtime.js not working on elements created after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, formatting, localtime

I am using localtime.js sucessfully on my app but now that ive started to use ajax
the elements created with ajax does not have the formatting that the plugin localtime does for me on my normal non ajax elements.
here's the local time plugin in im using
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-localtime/downloads/detail?name=jquery.localtime-0.5.js&can=2&q=
how can i re trigger it for the new elements that ajax created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your localtime plugin is listening for DOM readiness event like `$(document).ready()` to apply its formatting to the appropriate elements during the initial page load. Unless there is a similar link from your ajax success callback, in which new DOM content is inject, to those formatting functions, those functions will not be triggered and the desired formatting will not occur. In order to select and format elements added after the initial page load, you'll probably need to call your localtime formatting functions after you inject elements from your ajax call. This may involve enclosing your formatting process in a named function, which you would call once during initial page load, and again each time relevant content is injected.

If you were to show us your code, you could probably expect a more detailed and direct response.

Comment: thanks for the reply aaron. that is exactly what i want to do. hehe but my problem is i do not know how to "call your localtime formatting functions after you inject elements from your ajax call" because im not good at jquery/js. thats why im putting up a link to the plugin im using hoping that someone would be able to help me with that. thanks for the reply!

Comment: If you're hoping for someone to bridge the gap between the plugin's current functionality and what you need for your implementation, you'll probably need to post the code for/link to your app specifically. Otherwise, anyone who tries to help you won't be able to do much more than hope their solution fits into your system.

Answer (score 1):

thanks aaron
I've now added these lines of code at the last bit of my js response from ajax

```
var format;
var localise = function () {
    jQuery(this).text(jQuery.localtime.toLocalTime(jQuery(this).text(), format));
};
jQuery(".dateOnly:last").each(localise);
```

and it works!